# .NET shared classes between namespaces, how to distribute them?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, libraries

Some time ago I read from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0017SWPNO) that namespaces inside libraries should be distributed in a way that inner namespaces have more concrete classes than their parent namespaces. We can find an example of this inside the namespace `System.Net`, where we can find the class [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). This class has a higher abstraction level than [Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) which is inside the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace (in fact, `WebClient` uses `Socket`).

My question is, how about all those classes used by the parent and descendant namespaces? In which namespace should I put them? Should I create a new different one called something like `Parent.Shared` and import them from `Parent`, from `Parent.Child` and from `Parent.Child.GrandChild`?

Comment: It's going to be opinion based and even then, you're question is too *abstract* itself to offer sound advice.

Comment: This question is more architectural/engineering type of question which should be asked on [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @Mateusz when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Thank you for reminding, totally forgot about that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you have general purpose classes in parent namespace, and related classes in child namespaces. For example in System.Text you have not very related classes like `Encoding` or `StringBuilder`. In `System.Text.RegularExpressions` all the classes are related to regex.

Other approximation can be:
You define a set of interfaces in the parent namespace and a concrete implementation in each child namespace. For example
`DataLayer.Repository` can define interfaces to implement the repository pattern. And then you can have `DataLayer.Repository.EntityFramework` and `DataLayer.Repository.NHibernate` to implement that interfaces with different ORMs

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, It depends on the domain of the application and how many related classes I have. I would have Dolphin in Animals namespace, or would be in Animals.Mamals.Aquatic namespace

Comment: So what you suggest is putting general purpose classes (used by the descendant namespaces) along with higher abstraction level classes inside parent namespaces?